# Center modal with fade in scale up

Tags: css, modal-dialog, transform, centering

I'm struggling with centering the modal together with fade in and scale up:

```js
$('#md-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });

$('#md-close').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.md-modal {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-radius: .3rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  outline: 0;
}

.md-show {
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(40,43,49,.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show ~ .md-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-content {
    color: #333;
}

.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="md-trigger">Show</button>
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
  <div class="md-content">
    <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
      <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
      <button class="md-close" id="md-close">Close me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

The absolute positioning approach with transform:translate(-50%,-50%); isn't working for me. It has to be responsive so I can't use the margin-left approach. Do you have an idea why it is simply not displayed in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

Add this style to **md-modal-wrapper** class. added a **md-modal-wrapper** div to cover **md-modal** class

```
.md-modal-wrapper{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;    
}
```

Remove this style

```
.md-modal {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   position: absolute;
}
```

```js
$('#md-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
   e.preventDefault();
});

$('#md-close').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.md-modal {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 550px;
    z-index: 9999;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: .3rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
    outline: 0;
}
.md-show {
    visibility: visible;
}
.md-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(40,43,49,.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show ~ .md-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-content {
    color: #333;
}

.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
.md-modal-wrapper{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="md-trigger">Show</button>
<div class="md-modal-wrapper">

<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
  <div class="md-content">
    <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
      <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
      <button class="md-close" id="md-close">Close me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`scale(1)` was overriding the other `transform` property, `translate(-50%,-50%)`.

It can be easily fixed by combining them both: `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1)`.

```js
$('#md-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });

$('#md-close').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#modal-1').toggleClass("md-show"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.md-modal {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-radius: .3rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  outline: 0;
}

.md-show {
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(40,43,49,.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show ~ .md-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-content {
    color: #333;
}

.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="md-trigger">Show</button>
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
  <div class="md-content">
    <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
      <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
      <button class="md-close" id="md-close">Close me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but then the modal will scale from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

How about using flex?

Remove `position: absolute;` and `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` from md-modal

and cover the modal with flex div

```css
.md-container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
```

```
<div class="md-container">
  <div class="md-modal">
  ~~
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to use snippet so I'm attaching a codePen link

https://codepen.io/seongmin0801/pen/MWyrYvm

Comment: thanks for your approach, but the modal is not vertically centered then.

Answer (score -1):

Make `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) !important;`. There is `.md-show.md-effect-1 { transform: scale(1); }` that overrides it that's why you should use important

Comment: ah thanks, I haven't noticed that. But when I use !important, the fade effect doesn't work then. How can I combine both?

Comment: @barhatsor has the answer